# Getting value in String

Tags: android

Im using this code to get value from a string and then posting it after performing operation.

The problem is that after entering some value when I try to erase the entire text field it stops unexpectedly.Im using `onTextChanged` method and the piece of code that Im working with is here. Also it works fine when I use a Button to submit instead on `textWatcher`.

```
min=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
sec=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
millisec=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.milliseconds);
String minute = min.getText().toString();
Double   min1=Double.parseDouble(minute);
            min1=min1*60;
Double  min2=min1*1000;
sec.setText(Double.toString(min1));
millisec.setText(Double.toString(min2));
```

Comment: Are you unsetting the `TextWatcher` after you are done working with it? Also, a LogCat output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parseDouble will throw a NumberFormatException if you do not pass a parsable String...
So if you empty the field, you will get an exception.

You can wrap your code in a try-catch-clause:

```
String minute = min.getText().toString();

try{
   Double min1 = Double.parseDouble(
   min1=min1*60;

   Double min2=min1*1000;
   sec.setText(Double.toString(min1));
   millisec.setText(Double.toString(min2));
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
   sec.setText("");
   millisec.setText("");
}
```